# HTML Number Input: Only Allow Arrow Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Here is what I mean:

[image: Input Image]

Is it possible to only allow input via clicking the arrow buttons, and NOT from actually typing?

Ie: I could not type in "11", but if I click the up arrow 11 times then it will go to 11?

Here is my input field right now:

```
        <input type="number" min="00" max ="99" id="timer02_min" 
        maxlength="2" value="00">
```

Is there some native way of doing this? Or should I look more into buttons and some styling?

Comment: It seems like you don't really want an input, instead you want buttons bound to a value and the buttons will increment/decrease the minutes value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault()` in `keydown` event;

```js
// no keyboard
document.getElementById("timer02_min").addEventListener("keydown", e => e.preventDefault());

// allow up/down keyboard cursor buttons
document.getElementById("timer02_min2").addEventListener("keydown", e => e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 40 && e.preventDefault());
```

```html
no keyboard:
<input type="number" min="00" max ="99" id="timer02_min" 
        maxlength="2" value="00">
<br>
with up/down cursor keys:
<input type="number" min="00" max ="99" id="timer02_min2" 
        maxlength="2" value="00">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function change(n){
var num = document.getElementById("num");
var number1 = num.innerHTML;
var number = Number(number1);
var num2 = number.toString();
if(n == "s"){
  }else{
   number = number+n;
  }
  if(number <= 0){
  number = 0;
  }
  if(number > 99){
  number = 99;
  }
  if(num2.length == 1){
  var num1 = number;
  number = "0"+num1;
  }
  document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = number;
}
change("s");
```

```css
.input{
 border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.spinner-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
#inc-button{
 padding-top: 3.5px;
 background-color: #ccc;
  width: 14.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
   border: none;
   user-select: none; /* Standard */
}
#dec-button{
 cursor: pointer;
 padding-top: 3px;
 background-color: #ccc;
  width: 14.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border: none;
  user-select: none; /* Standard */
}
#inc-button:hover,#dec-button:hover{
background-color: #b5b5b5;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer02_min" class="input">
  <div id="num">00</div>
  <div class="spinner-button">
  <div onclick="change(1);" id="inc-button">+</div>
  <div onclick="change(-1);" id="dec-button">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try This!

The Number you want to start put it in the `#num` *div*.